# Phaser / TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest

In my game, I want to save the updated score from the user and then retrieve the ranking from the DB. I understood that Promises are the way to go, and I already tried many answers here on Stack Overflow but I cannot figure out why I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

With this function, I update the score for the user:

```
saveScoreOnDb: function () {
    var self = this;

    if(!this.scoreUpdated && (this.score > this.game.global.currentUser.high_score)){
        // do this just once
        this.scoreUpdated = true;

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // save current score on Db
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("PUT", "https://myproject.herokuapp.com/api/users/" + self.game.global.currentUser.id, true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            var input = JSON.stringify({
                'high_score': self.score
            });

            xhttp.onload = function(){
                if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhttp.status == 200){
                    console.log('resolved the savetoDB thingy');
                    resolve(xhttp.response);
                }
            };
            xhttp.onerror = function(){
                reject(xhttp.statusText);
            };

            xhttp.send(input);
        });
    } else {
        self.getRankingFromDb();
    }
}
```

In another function, inside a switch, I call the function with this code:

```
this.saveScoreOnDb().then(function(reply){
    console.log('promise: ', + reply);
    self.getRankingFromDb();
});
```

What is going wrong in this case?

Comment: You need to **ALWAYS** return a promise. You are only sometimes returning a promise

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? Should I just add a return statement returning a dummy message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always return a promise. The promise can be dummy text, `null`, `undefined`, `void`, etc. You choose but you need to always return a promise in order to use `.then()` or `.catch()`.

So here I just moved the promise up a few lines above the `if`, and made the `else` `resolve` (otherwise you will never resolve if you enter the `if`). You could also reject it if you want that is your choice.

You will also need to replace `this` with `self`

```
saveScoreOnDb: function () {
  var self = this;

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (!self.scoreUpdated && (self.score > self.game.global.currentUser.high_score)) {
      // do this just once
      self.scoreUpdated = true;

      // save current score on Db
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.open("PUT", "https://myproject.herokuapp.com/api/users/" + self.game.global.currentUser.id, true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      var input = JSON.stringify({
        'high_score': self.score
      });

      xhttp.onload = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhttp.status == 200) {
          console.log('resolved the savetoDB thingy');
          resolve(xhttp.response);
        }
      };
      xhttp.onerror = function () {
        reject(xhttp.statusText);
      };

      xhttp.send(input);
    } else {
      resolve(self.getRankingFromDb());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! At least now I do not get the undefined error. However, the behavior is still wrong, since it displays the ranking but with the old score from the player. It should update it first and then show the ranking..

Comment: I also notices another issue: when I try to print the response I get in the .then() part, I get Nan

Comment: Solved it! You pinted me in the right direction, I just resolve null in the else and then I do an additional check in my switch code: if it's not null, retrieve the ranking

Comment: Glad I could help